# Trouble learning React Class components with generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to wrap my head around how this is supposed to work. I have a base class with props. Then I have an interface for the props for the child class. I am getting the typescript error

`Property 'lineWidth' does not exist on type 'Readonly<BasicChartProps<LineChartProps<T>>>'.ts(2339)`

here is my sample code example

```
import React from 'react';

export interface BasicChartProps<T> {
  data: T[];
  x_key: keyof T;
  y_key: keyof T;
}

export type BasicChartState<T> = {
  data: T[];
  x_key: keyof T;
  y_key: keyof T;
  x_margin: number;
  y_margin: number;
};

export class BasicChart<T> extends React.Component<
  BasicChartProps<T>,
  BasicChartState<T>
> {
  state: BasicChartState<T> = {
    x_margin: 50,
    y_margin: 50,
    data: this.props.data || [],
    x_key: this.props.x_key,
    y_key: this.props.y_key,
  };

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>x_margin: {this.state.x_margin}</div>
        <div>y_margin: {this.state.y_margin}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export interface LineChartProps<T> extends BasicChartProps<T> {
  lineWidth: number;
}

export class LineChart<T> extends BasicChart<LineChartProps<T>> {
  render(): React.ReactNode {
    const {lineWidth} = this.props;
    return <div>lineWidth: {lineWidth}</div>;
  }
}
```

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: `BasicChart` uses `BasicChartProps` which only has the properties `data`, `x_key` and `y_key`.

Comment: const {lineWidth} = this.props is where the error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of hacky, but you can pass `LineChartProps` as another template variable:

```
import React from "react";

export type BasicChartProps<T, K> = K & {
  data: T[];
  x_key: keyof T;
  y_key: keyof T;
}

export type BasicChartState<T> = {
  data: T[];
  x_key: keyof T;
  y_key: keyof T;
  x_margin: number;
  y_margin: number;
};

export class BasicChart<T, K> extends React.Component<
  BasicChartProps<T, K>,
  BasicChartState<T>
> {
  state: BasicChartState<T> = {
    x_margin: 50,
    y_margin: 50,
    data: this.props.data || [],
    x_key: this.props.x_key,
    y_key: this.props.y_key
  };

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>x_margin: {this.state.x_margin}</div>
        <div>y_margin: {this.state.y_margin}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export interface LineChartProps {
  lineWidth: number;
}

export class LineChart<T> extends BasicChart<T, LineChartProps> {
  render(): React.ReactNode {
    const x = this.props;
    x.
    return <div>lineWidth: {lineWidth}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I really do like this approach. It seems pretty simple and appears to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Passing `LineChartProps` to `BasicChart`'s type parameter passes it to `BasicChartProps`'s type parameter which then gets used on various properties on that interface. Here's a visualisation:

```
class LineChart<T> extends BasicChart<LineChartProps<T>> { ... }
                  ____________________________|
                 |
                 v
class BasicChart<T>
                 |______________________
                                        |
                                        v
extends React.Component<BasicChartProps<T>, BasicChartState<T>> { ... }
                           _____________|
                          |
                          v
interface BasicChartProps<T> {
         _________________|
        |                 |
        v                 |
  data: T[];    __________|
               |          |
               v          |
  x_key: keyof T;         |
                __________|
               |
               v
  y_key: keyof T;
}
```

## Solution

I suspect the above isn't what was intended and that you're trying to get the type of `LineChart`'s type parameter passed all the way down to `BasicChartProps`. Like this?

```
                 ____________________________________
                |                                    |
                |                                    v
class LineChart<T> extends BasicChart<LineChartProps<T>> { ... }
                          ___________________________|
                         |
                         v
interface LineChartProps<T>
                        _|
                        |  
                        v
extends BasicChartProps<T>
                        |_
                          |
                          v
interface BasicChartProps<T> {
         _________________|
        |                 |
        v                 |
  data: T[];    __________|
               |          |
               v          |
  x_key: keyof T;         |
                __________|
               |
               v
  y_key: keyof T;
}
```

To get that to work, I think something like this would be ideal:

```
class BasicChart<Props extends BasicChartProps<?>> extends React.Component<
                   |                           ʌ
/* Somehow extract the type parameter */       |
                  _|___________________________|
                  |
  Props,          |
                  v
  BasicChartState<?>
> { ... }
```

I think it's possible by updating `BasicChart` to the following:

```
type FirstGenericTypeParameter<Props extends BasicChartProps<any>> = Props extends BasicChartProps<infer T> ? T : never;

export class BasicChart<
  Props extends BasicChartProps<T>,
  T = FirstGenericTypeParameter<Props>
> extends React.Component<
  Props,
  BasicChartState<T>
> { ... }
```

The [`infer` keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) is used to extract the (first) generic type parameter from `Props` and assign it to `T`. `T` is then passed to `BasicChartProps` and `BasicChartState`.

Here's a [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljmADsYkpN0k4AhFAZ2DQBhABYpYABRxheAHgAqAPjgBvcnDgATFDBQAuOHIDaAXQrrqAfQDWSAJ76btiJgNm4t63Yd3nr8gF9KGjp4GFswTh5+IVFYAGUdFnklAF4VNU1tPQMTN0tHbycXOTcPArhHXxKMyxAxAHMmfUYAVxAAI1ZSizqoRsZmts6oCn8KcjCIuAAxYCheGABxJEZWATlwpHExFBAkFigZSQhpOBoWRg1ebj4BETEYY+kZFEZbBVS4J+vzlaub6L3CRSWRMTCsAxKAD8BjgzSQADcukFaNB4GgADZ8a5RO6xGAyDLfM7UC7-XExB7fZIAGgycjgaVm8yWKzWaA2EW2UF2+1YRxBCnISl+l2uyHQMAAdIJcJBVsxCepvnT1BSgTAEtokMlhel1Attfp1fitUlFIz9eo4LUGk04ABWAAMqutHl6-X0ztd6i0On0MGEwF4UrAIKlfpQcAAPtG4CYfTbPPY4IHg6Hw-k7Imyl5U0GQ2GTiHc7ZXWNKOoiJdWAAKACU+glGClzZgADkIBpOKprXAiDAWlBGHBaxk+zINMAEUK+xOpzPbX17co0yHDSwpUv+v4ZAB6BezufqSfThTuu0DFRrqUbpBSi-Lxi7g9n8fW-eH9-1tyBQJUVF6CYA52DQTgABkmCQDVqQtUVyVuSlgWLZIrQxKCAHVgA0QNBg6ZF-2CNE4ExbE4Eg1YNVQ+CcUQqiKOg-FYI+K1q27KAGybYhpTbTtuytdQ0AgRgFhUdDViwnDhH8S0byLaQ3CrfYhxHU8Z3EpBJNwsTMOwwMX0PX8AkoUjeGuaYIAgBiNRJMlrms-EZGUOBMEs-QFigJh6jgfwlF7fs-jret0nfOTw0jQwnWMKVXIgOA9z3OAPK80KCwzYst2TeLEoAIlinLUvTeSSyyhK4DyyyCr7MKMo0rThGyuBWnwqBK2tG87wjLJIui2LGuSxh6kK9dEnvLNbEaiqICq9q0s60tJvy4bb1GzKPSYRrmuGZb5p6S9NqGVg2qUwdh1HGQFH3BQfwyP8gA) in TypeScript Playground. At the end is the following to test things work as expected (do play around yourself to verify things work to your own expectations):

```
class FooLineChart extends LineChart<{ foo: string }> {
  render() {

    this.props.data[0].foo // string
    this.props.x_key // "foo"
    this.props.y_key // "foo"
    this.props.lineWidth // number

    this.state.data[0].foo // string
    this.state.x_key // "foo"
    this.state.y_key // "foo"
    this.state.x_margin // number
    this.state.y_margin // number

    return (<></>);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the super in-depth answer. I am going to have to process on this for a little while to wrap my head around it.